# Excel formula to return 4 values in a specific pattern of combinations (Yankee bet)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a range whose values I'd like returned in specific pattern of combinations.

In betting, the particular pattern is called a "Yankee."  Four events are arranged into these 11 combinations:

- 1 Fourfold (4 event combination)
- 4 Trebles (unique 3-event combination)
- 6 Doubles (unique 2-event combination)

How would I create a formula in Excel that would return this pattern of combinations?

**Example Values**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | one |  |
| **2** | two |  |
| **3** | three |  |
| **4** | four |  |

A single **Fourfold** combination that includes all the values in the range

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | one | **one, two, three, four** |
| **2** | two |  |
| **3** | three |  |
| **4** | four |  |

Four **Trebles** which are as many unique<sup>*</sup> 3-value combinations as can be created from the range.
<sub>* *In any order, the same 3 values can't apear together more than once*</sub>

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | one | one, two, three, four |
| **2** | two | **one, two, three** |
| **3** | three | **one, two, four** |
| **4** | four | **one, three, four** |
| **5** |  | **two, three, four** |

Lastly, six **Doubles** which are as many unique<sup>*</sup> 2-value combinations as can be created from the range.
<sub>* *In any order, the same 2 values can't apear together more than once*</sub>

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | one | one, two, three, four |
| **2** | two | one, two, three |
| **3** | three | one, two, four |
| **4** | four | one, three, four |
| **5** |  | two, three, four |
| **6** |  | **one, two** |
| **7** |  | **one, three** |
| **8** |  | **one, four** |
| **9** |  | **two, three** |
| **10** |  | **two, four** |
| **11** |  | **three, four** |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=LET(arr,A1:A4,
     sa,{1;2;3;4},sb,{1;1;1;2;2;3}, sc,{2;3;4;3;4;4},
     four,TEXTJOIN(", ",,arr),
     three,MAP(sa, LAMBDA(a,
       TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(arr,arr<>INDEX(arr,a))))),
     two,MAP(sb,sc, LAMBDA(b,c,
       TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(arr,b),INDEX(arr,c)))),
     VSTACK(four,three,two))
```

[image]

The formula uses the [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function to enable storing intermediary values in arbitrarily named variables for later reuse.

The formula joins values using [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) which always has the `delimiter` argument set to `", "` and `ignore_empty` left empty.  In my description below,  I simply use 'join(s)' as a shorthand and describe only the `text1,[text2],…` argument(s) where necessary.

*"it then joins `a` and `b`"*   is equivalent to   `TEXTJOIN(", ",,a,b)`

I expect there is a math formula for calculating the combinations for each group.  I simply created number sequences that matched the combinations you provided for each group.

1. `four` (1 x fourfold) is the simplest.  It simply joins all 4 values from `arr`
2. `three` (4 x threefold) uses [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) to pass a sequence `sa` of 4 numbers `1,2,3,4` one by one into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function

   - the numbers in `sa` together represent all of the [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) positions of the values in `arr`
   - [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) represents the currently mapped value in its formula as `a`
   - For each `a` the formula [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)'s `arr` by excluding the value found at position `a` and then joining each result.
3. `two` (6 x twofold) maps the sequences `sb` and `sc`, each containing 6 numbers, into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function

   - `sb` contains the positions in `arr` of the first value in each of `two`'s 6 combinations
   - `sc` contains the positions in `arr` of the second value in each of `two`'s 6 combinations
   - using `b` and `c` to represent the currently mapped values, for each pair of `b` and `c`, the formula joins the two values found at those positions in `arr`
4. [VSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) returns the resulting arrays `four,three,two` one below the other.

Comment: Thats exactly what i meant, thanks a lot, if i want to add a fifth selection or more, are there many changes to be made in this formula

Comment: @LoomeshAppadoo what do you mean by a *"fifth selection"* are you talking about a "Canadian/Super Yankee"?